# Linkbuttons visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security

Please could someone advise me on the best way for me to show a button to a few people but not to everyone who will access my app, this is my Code:

```
        var a = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

        var adEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + a[0] + "/" + a[1]);
        var userName = adEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();
        LinkButton5.Visible = userName == "name 1";
        //LinkButton5.Visible = userName == "name 2";
        //LinkButton5.Visible = userName == "name 3";
        //LinkButton5.Visible = userName == "name 4";
```

as you can see if i can only allow one name how can i allow the others

Comment: it's called permissions

Comment: There are a lot of answers possible. First of all, make clear what your requirements are. Do you have to check for roles, etc.?

Comment: not getting when you want to display link button... please add some more information

Comment: sorry i'm a little new to all this, so.. i want certain people to see an admin section at the moment i can get name 1 to get access but as soon as i un-comment name 2, 3 and 4 every user then can gain access

Comment: you must create a table where you will group users by role, the name of user is intended to change at any time

Comment: In short you want authentication...is it so??

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually have done something like this:

```
// Create hash list to hold allowed users
HashSet<string> allowed_users = new HashSet<string>();

// Add users here

// Get current user
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + a[0] + "/" + a[1]);
var username = entry.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();

// Toggle link button
LinkButton.Visible = allowed_users.Contains(username);
```